# Problem changing background color of tr in firefox using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table with rows which have alternating classes, I am trying to highlight the row hovered on using css.

Here is the CSS I use:

```
.gridrowclass1 {
    background-color : #bbb00b
}

.gridrowclass1:hover {
    background-color: bisque;
}

.gridrowclass2 {  
    background-color: #d18915;
}

.gridrowclass2:hover {
    background-color: bisque;
}
```

This works fine on chrome, but does not on Firefox 3.6.18. My question is am I doing something wrong here or this is a problem with the Firefox version I use and if this would work on newer versions.
I currently cannot try this out on any other browser. Googling did not reveal anything that I missed. If this does not work, I would have to fall back on onMouse* events but I do not want to do that.

Comment: have you tried checking firebug to see if any styles are overriding the `tr?` Sometimes you might need to write your css like this: `table tbody tr.gridrowclass1 { ... }`

Comment: I tried on firefox 3.6.17 without having problems. Like what Xavier said, you might want to post your html code for your table so we can help you take a better look. The CSS is definitely correct.

Comment: A fail safe solution is to just use jQuery ? :D

Comment: I think I am gonna have to go with JS. Lucky for me I am using an HTML generator and don't have to change every table in my app.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue some time ago. 
I came around by using:

```
.gridrowclass1 {
    background-color : #bbb00b
}

.gridrowclass1 td:hover {
    background-color: bisque;
}

.gridrowclass2 {  
    background-color: #d18915;
}

.gridrowclass2 td:hover {
    background-color: bisque;
}
```

it seems that firefox does not recognize hover of a tr if the mouse is over a td element

Comment: Won't that just change the color of the cell that you're hovering over, not the whole row?

Comment: You are correct, this seems to be the problem i.e. FF not recognizing hover over tr however I want to highlight the entire row and not just the td the mouse is over. Is JS the only option?

Comment: Have you tried `.gridrowclass1:hover td { background-color:... }`? I don't have Firefox atm so I can't test it.

Comment: hm it does work. so its not the problem that firefox is not recognizing the mouse hover for tr

Comment: @Tim Rogers: Doesn't work. Although logically it seems it should. And I tested this does work on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the missing semi-colon after the first color value is a problem. I think that it is the problem - try adding that semicolon - it should work

Comment: That's not the problem, The semi colon after the last element is not required anyway.